# divided window into the number of valid value 1 ~ 8

Tags: c++, window, screen, protocols, divide

i have trouble understanding part of protocol, this protocol is for LED screen controller C-Power 5200, i must write hex value of window which is divided from screen like this: if i have 8 window value must be 0x08 but i want split screen into 15 window, about value in protocol is written like this:
[image]
i can't understand how i must divide into number of valid value 1 ~ 8, what this part means? 
this is my full packet structure:

```
     $window_collector_cc = "0x01,0x09,0x00,

     0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x58,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,

     0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x50,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x58,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,

     0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x08,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x50,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     0x58,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x08,0x00,
     ";
```

in this packet 0x09 is amount of window which does not works because of 1~8 divide which i can't understand, if i will make for example <0x08 it works... each line is window with options (X,Y,W,H), Please help me understand this line of protocol. sorry if question is not correctly opened just answer me and i will delete if something wrong.

Comment: Do the controller really *allow* you to divide the screen into arbitrary number of "windows"?

Comment: It looks like valid numbers are in the range 1 to 8, so you **CAN'T** use higher number, at least while you won't change the controller.

Comment: this controller have his own software called Led Center which allows split at last 18 window